# Sequelize Terminology: Association vs Relation vs Relationship

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm wondering what the difference between the terms "association", "relation" and "relationship" is, with regards to the Sequelize ORM for node.js.

I found some documentation [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html), and some (presumably) older documentation [here](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/associations/). The three terms are used all over the place, yet I feel like there may be some nuances causing them to not be fully interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in terms of the code... you are using association to associate one model to another.. I'm sure they use the terms interchangeably here and there but whenever you look at code examples for relating models to one another you'll be calling the associate function on that model so set those up like

```
Profile.associate = function (models) {
    models.Profile.hasOne(models.ProfileCompanyInfo, { as: 'CompanyInfo', foreignKey: 'id' });
    models.Profile.hasMany(models.ProfileProject, { as: 'Projects', foreignKey: 'author' });
  };
```

Comment: To add on, I now think that in DBMS, "relation" is short for "relation schema", aka tables, but is also used to refer to one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many relationships, ie "one-to-one relation between two tables". Meanwhile, "association" seems to be a term coined by Sequelize.js, representing those 3 types of relationships in an abstracted form. Models can have BelongsTo, HasOne, HasMany or BelongsToMany associations.

Comment: Exactly... when you are having trouble with your queries and the relationships between your tables within them, you’ll just want to look at the docs for associations from sequelize, or there is a wealth of knowledge on here as well!!